# Survival mode not appearing?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I have completed adventure but I don't have survival mode yet. Is this a glitch? Do I have to complete adventure 2? Or does the version not have survival? I am playing the Ipad version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The plantsvszombies wiki states](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Survival_Mode):

> The iPad has Survival Mode but does not have Survival: Hard. It does have Survival: Endless, however.

So it sounds like a glitch or a regression.